# setLocale not working properly, setting a new language does not change anything

Tags: android

I implemented the `setLocale` earlier in my app, and haven't checked it until yesterday. The changing of language was working properly, but now setting a new language does not change the language in my app. The way it works, is as follows: I added a spinner in my `Profile activity` in the toolbar. I use an adapter to create the `spinner`'s look to show the name and a flag. It used to work, when I was changing the spinner, with a `onItemSelectedListener` I managed to change the language, but now it's not working anymore.

EDIT: Following @Hardik Talaviya's answer I added the `LocaleManager class` and changed the code, but the app behaves the same. It does not change the language according to the spinner selection.

LocaleManager.class:

```
public class LocaleManager {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }
    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
    localeList.setDefault(localeList);
    configuration.setLocales(localeList);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

Added this method on all activities that uses `strings`:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.onAttach(newBase));
}
```

`OnItemSelectedListener` :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
    pozitie = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if (!clickedCountryName.equals(lastCountryName)) {
        lastCountryName = clickedCountryName;
        if (clickedCountryName.equals("FR")) {
            Context context= getBaseContext();
            LocaleManager.setLocale(context, "fr");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profil.this, Profil.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("RO")) {
            LocaleManager.setLocale(this, "ro");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profil.this, Profil.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("EN")) {
            LocaleManager.setLocale(this, "en");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Profil.this, Profil.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below class

**LocaleManager.java**

```
public class LocaleManager {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }
        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
        localeList.setDefault(localeList);
        configuration.setLocales(localeList);
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return context;
    }
}
```

Add **attachBaseContex** override method in all activity

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleManager.onAttach(newBase));
}
```

Now,**change language** using this code

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TaraITEM clickedItem = (TaraITEM) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String clickedCountryName = clickedItem.getCountryName();
    pozitie = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();

    if (!clickedCountryName.equals(lastCountryName)) {
        lastCountryName = clickedCountryName;
        if (clickedCountryName.equals("FR")) {
            LocaleManager.setLocale(context, "fr");
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("RO")) {
            LocaleManager.setLocale(context, "ro");
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else if (clickedCountryName.equals("EN")) {
            LocaleManager.setLocale(context, "en");
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: I have added the class and made all the changes, but it still does not change the language

Comment: @Costin what issue generated?not restart activity?

Comment: There is no issue generated. When i switch the spinner to another country, this line `Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);` is executed, but the the `LocaleManager.setLocale(context, "en");` does not change the language

Comment: Are you set different language string xml?

Comment: Yes, I've implemented all the languages from the spinner with translations editor

Comment: Are you add attachBaseContext?

Comment: Yes, I've added `attachBaseContext` to all applications that are using strings

Comment: this is working fine for me may be you are doing any wrong from your side.If it is possible uninstall and again install app

Comment: I tried reinstalling, still no change. Thanks for the code, I will try to get back at it and maybe there's something wrong when I added it.

Comment: For `context` ,should I go with `this`, `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: No It's normal context.

Comment: I have to initialize it with something then, because I do not have any `context` variable set

Comment: Try to add getApplicationContext()

Comment: Remove `setLocale(limba, pozitie_limba);` this from onCreate

Comment: I updated the question. Took out all the other parts of the code from the first try

Comment: Are you remove `setLocale(limba, pozitie_limba);` from onCreate?

Comment: Yes, I did remove that

Comment: attachBaseContext this need to add all your activity not for only where string use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208180/discussion-between-costin-and-hardik-talaviya).